# Wallpaper visibililty changes

Tags: android

In Android, how is a wallpaper service notified when visibility changes occur?
I have gone through AOSP code, but i am not able to figure that out.

I guess it should be WindowManagerService, can anybody clarify?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

[`WallpaperService.Engine.onVisibilityChanged(boolean)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/service/wallpaper/WallpaperService.Engine.html#onVisibilityChanged%28boolean%29) receives this information:

> Called to inform you of the wallpaper becoming visible or hidden. *It is very important that a wallpaper only use CPU while it is visible*.

This method gets invoked indirectly by a message sent from the Android system to the activity holding the surface used to display the live wallpaper. In version `5.1.0 r1` it has a message code of

```
private static final int MSG_VISIBILITY_CHANGED = 10010;
```

This message gets intercepted by an internal class `IWallpaperEngineWrapper` of `WallpaperService` implementing `com.android.internal.os.HandlerCaller.Callback`.

Just add `Thread.dumpStack();` to your implementation and see yourself.

Comment: Yeah, thats true, but i am wondering who notifies wallpaperservice that there has been a change in visibility!!

Comment: @TanmayVarun I see. Just had a look at the stack. If you're looking for the source of the message it might get a little more ugly though.

Comment: Yeah, not able to exactly figure out, will check if dispatchappwindowvisibility is calling..